# mysql - problems with escaping and reading array values as columns rather than values

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  lastName
FROM
  users
WHERE
  name IN (??)
```

and then use it like this:

```js
   import { sqlQuerySeenAbove } from './sql/queries'

   async function createReport() {
    try {
      const arrOfStrings = ['John', 'Laura']
      const pool = await getConnection()
      const res = pool.query(sqlQuerySeenAbove, conn.escape(arrOfStrings))
      console.log('res -->', res)
    } catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
```

the error message that I am getting is:

> "Unknown column ''John', 'Laura'' in 'where clause'",

> name IN (`'John', 'Laura'`)\n"

I think the problem is that within this `()` section the mysql is placing the back ticks to signal that it is looking for the column rather than the values. the [mysql docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values) say that when escaping characters:

- Arrays are turned into list, e.g. ['a', 'b'] turns into 'a', 'b'

also the [escaping identifiers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers) has a similar query as mine so I am not sure what the issue is. I am aware that within the docs it says also that the `??` is used as a placeholder for escaped characters, but, if I do:

```js
pool.query(sqlQuerySeenAbove, arrOfStrings)
```

I get the error:

> "Unknown column 'John' in 'where clause'",

*note*: I understand that escaping has it's own issues in terms of security but this is internal usage, so for argument sake let's say that we aren't worried about any sql injection

what I would like is a return of this:

```
/------------------------------------\
| id | name | lastName               |
|------------------------------------|
| 1  | John | Smith                  |
|------------------------------------|
| 2  | John | Doe                    |
|------------------------------------|
| 3  | Laura| Smith                  |
|------------------------------------|
| 4  | Laura| Doe                    |
\------------------------------------/
```

Answer (score 0):

my issue was that I had to change a couple things:

1. in the query you don't use `(??)` use only `(?)` this is because the `??` is short hand for escaping and therefore will look for the column name instead of the value
2. where executing the command you don't need to get the connection and escape, for the same reason as above so: `pool.query(sqlQuerySeenAbove, arrOfStrings)`
3. the `arrOfStrings` needs to be a nested array, so the final solution is: `pool.query(sqlQuerySeenAbove, [arrOfStrings])`

the reason for #3 is because if you had multiple values it will iterate through that and search for that value:

```
[['John', 'Laura'], ['Smith', 'Doe']]
```

mysql will iterate through the first array, then the second.